# Cannot get _.debounce() to work

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am having trouble trying to get underscore.debounce() to work. I am attaching a keydown event listener on an input field. I will perform some actions, then call debounce() which is not being called. I am wondering why it is not working?

I have provided two samples. The first one where I have not attached `_.debounce()` as inline is not working. The second one where I have attached `_.debounce()` as inline is working. I do not understand why the non-inline solution is working?

```
// This example does not ever call _.debounce()
$('input').on('keydown', onKeyDown);
function onKeyDown() {
    console.log('performing some actions...');

    _.debounce(function() {
        console.log('debouncing'); // never called
    }, 500);
}


// This example does call _.debounce()
$('input').on('keydown', _.debounce(function() {
    console.log('debounce');
}, 500));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debounce returns a function that will need to be invoked, in this case you are creating a function but never invoking it.  Try this:

```
// This example does not ever call _.debounce()
var debounced = _.debounce(debounceStuff, 500);
$('input').on('keydown', onKeyDown);
function onKeyDown() {
    console.log('performing some actions...');

    debounced();
}

function debounceStuff() {
    console.log('debouncing');
}
```